# Can CodeRush show "access to modified closure" issue?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, coderush

I know that R# can show this type of issues. But can CodeRush do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this [devexpress-post](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S136710) its not possible for now, but on todo-list.